# Problems with fonts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I publish with IIS my project that is in MVC, I get the following errors

```
GET http://localhost:8082/Elaguilaportal/Content/Content/font/socicon-webfont.woff                                         (index):398
GET http://localhost:8082/Elaguilaportal/Content/Content/font/socicon-webfont.woff2                                        (index):1
GET http://localhost:8082/Elaguilaportal/Content/lib/materialize/font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.woff2    (index):483 
GET http://localhost:8082/Elaguilaportal/Content/Content/font/socicon-webfont.ttf                                          (index):483
```

This is how the errors look like in the link that left [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlfl3.jpg)

Checking many forums on the internet I tried many things but none works for me, the route is correct, in addition to the files if they are where indicated

This is how I refer

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'socicon';
    src: url('../font/socicon-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../font/socicon-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/socicon-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../font/socicon-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../font/socicon-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../font/socicon-webfont.svg#sociconregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-transform: initial;
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Material-Design-Icons";
src: url("../font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.woff") format("woff"), url("../font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.svg#Material-Design-Icons") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; }
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Structure of my solution [image: link]

Comment: The screenshot appears to indicate that the GET request for the font definition files fail? If so, then what error do you see? 1. check in your browser console, in the networking tab in there and 2. in your http servers error log file.

Comment: Is this the real location of the font `Elaguilaportal/Content/Content/font`?

Comment: In your screenshot there is also error for the image file, starting with path `Images`, while other requests start with `Elaguilaportal`. Are u using bundling?

Comment: if the location, check it well

Comment: if I have reviewed the route of all the errors that eme appear in the errors, but if all the routes of my files are well and I do not know why that appears

Comment: Could yo add screenshot of your solution, so I can see the file structure?

Comment: According to added the question

Comment: I am asking because there are also error for the `ttf` files. If we are talking about `woff` files, you should add this to your web.config, because IIS is not configured to serve `woff` files with right mime type by default `<system.webServer>
 <staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
 </staticContent>
</system.webServer>`

Comment: If I also probe the <staticContent> tag but it does not fix anything

Comment: I still think that you misspelled paths for the fonts. You can not have in the same css file `../Content/font/socicon-webfont.eot` and also `../font/socicon-webfont.eot?#iefix'`. `../` makes it go one level up, and one goes down to `Content` folder and the other goes to `font` folder, it can not work

Comment: the actual path is ../font/socicon-webfont.eot, the content was put to test, I made the screenshot before switching to the actual one that is src: url ('../source/socicon-webfont. eot '); ..... but still I get error

Comment: All the paths you have in the css file, are relative to the path of the css file. If you download the css file from path`http://localhost:8082/Elaguilaportal/Content/css/MYCSS.css` and in that file you reference the font file like this `'../font/socicon-webfont.eot'` the font should be in the `Content/font` folder. Does this apply for all your references?

Comment: Content/font  .... This is how I apply this for all references

Comment: And what's the result?

Comment: already update the image of the route so that you see that everything makes reference to the same route